# Passing Jwt token in header from swagger UI as bearer token not working

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, swagger, bearer-token

I am generating jwt token web api core application. In application i am using swagger and applied bearer token authentication.but when i am try pass  bearer token  from swagger UI i am getting 401 error.please anyone help me on this

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v2" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,               
            });

        });


app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Versioned API v2.0");

            c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
        });
```

[image]
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F84Im.png)
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqLn7.png)

Answer (score 9):

You have specified SecurityScheme that supported by your API, but did not specify that its required. So, swagger will not going to pass that in header.For this you need to use `OpenApiSecurityRequirement` and within that specify Id of `SecurityDefinition` that you have used.
Here is a snippet that I have used.

```
var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    Scheme = "bearer",
    BearerFormat = "JWT" // Optional
};

var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "bearerAuth"
            }
        },
        new string[] {}
    }
};

options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", securityScheme);
options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);
```