# JWT Authentication with Swagger .NET Core 6

Tags: jwt, swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to develop an application. For Authentication I am using JWT Token. I have successfully created token. And using Postman I can authenticated. But Swagger I did whatever I should do but, It doesn't work.

After authenticated as you can see,The lock icon in the upper right is active, but the lock icons on the right of the endpoints do not work.
[image: Swagger Docs After Authenticed with token]

You can find the code part below:

JWT Authentication Part:

```
//JwtAuthentication
var tokenOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection(TokenOptions.OptionSectionName).Get<TokenOptions>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = SignService.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

Swagger Gen Section:

```
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("V1",new OpenApiInfo{
        Version = "V1",
        Title = "Educal API",
        Description = "Main API Documantation of Educal API"
    });
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer,", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "Please insert your JWT Token into field",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT"
        });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
                Reference = new OpenApiReference{
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });

    
});
```

And Finally Swagger and Swagger UI section:

```
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json","Main API Documantation of Educal API");
});
```

Token is created successfully. When send a request from swagger to an endpoint Authorize tag I realized that swagger don't add to parameter.
For example:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:7086/api/Manager/e1433dd0-ad45-456f-97e1-9f074e665feb' \
  -H 'accept: */*'
```

By the way when sending request from Postman with header contains token, I can get to result.

Updated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337464/13490329 This answer solved my problem.

Comment: Try to use  F12 to check your network, and don't you find some errors in your console?

Comment: Could you share more code about your Program.cs?